# Kraken.com API: Generate the message signature in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular, encoding, cryptography, cryptojs

I am trying to learn Angular2 and as a first exercise, I would like to retrieve data from the Kraken.com API. (I know, I could have chose something easier :)

Well, for "Public" calls it works just fine. Now I am trying to call the "Private" methods. (Those one need to be authenticated)

As precised here:
https://www.kraken.com/help/api

The expected signature is:

```
API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key
```

So I am trying to generate that... Without success... I constantly receive this error message:

```
Kraken API returned an error: API:Invalid nonce
```

But I am pretty sure my nonce is correct, so I would rather think it is related to data encryption.

I've found [here](https://github.com/nothingisdead/npm-kraken-api/blob/master/kraken.js) a function that should do the job, but I can't use it "as-is" in my angular project.

```
/**
 * This method returns a signature for a request as a Base64-encoded string
 * @param  {String}  path    The relative URL path for the request
 * @param  {Object}  request The POST body
 * @param  {Integer} nonce   A unique, incrementing integer
 * @return {String}          The request signature
 */
function getMessageSignature(path, request, nonce) {
    var message = querystring.stringify(request);
    var secret  = new Buffer(config.secret, 'base64');
    var hash    = new crypto.createHash('sha256');
    var hmac    = new crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret);

    var hash_digest = hash.update(nonce + message).digest('binary');
    var hmac_digest = hmac.update(path + hash_digest, 'binary').digest('base64');

    return hmac_digest;
}
```

and here is my code:

```
private getMessageSignature(path: string, request: any, nonce: number) {
    //API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key

    var message = this.querystring.stringify(request);
    var secret  = this.CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(this.config.secret);
    var hash_digest = this.CryptoJS.SHA256(nonce + message);
    var hmac    = this.CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(path + hash_digest, secret).toString(this.CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    return hmac;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely `path + hash_digest` which is a type mismatch which leads to strange results, because `hash_digest` will be hex-encoded and not used in its binary representation.

The following might work:

```
var hmac = this.CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(path + hash_digest.toString(this.CryptoJS.enc.Latin1), secret).toString(this.CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

but the following is a much better alternative:

```
var hmacHasher = this.CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(this.CryptoJS.algo.SHA512, secret);
hmacHasher.update(path);
hmacHasher.update(hash_digest);
var hmac = hmacHasher.finalize().toString(this.CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Comment: Have you made sure the path and the request are correctly encoded?

Comment: Arf, my comment was truncated and I can't even answer to my own thread. Here is my original reply (with my updated code) http://pastebin.com/zVcgGcsC  Thank Artjom !

Comment: No, idea. I haven't looked at the Kraken API

Answer (score -1):

Ouhou ! Thanks to your help Artjom, I finally successed to make my API call !

Before actually showing the code, I had to change something:
In my query, I passed the parameters as

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

And there was a mismatch between the actual data sent and the data used to compute the signature. 
So I had to correct this so the data that is sent in my request body is the exact same as the one used in the signature computation:

```
let paramsStr = this.querystring.stringify(params);
```

Ok, finally, here is the code to compute the signature:

```
private getMessageSignature(path: string, request: any, nonce: number) {
        //API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of 
        // (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key

        var message = this.querystring.stringify(request);
        var secret = this.CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(this.config.secret);
         var hash256 = this.CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create();
        hash256.update(String(nonce));
        hash256.update(message);

        var hmacHasher = this.CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(this.CryptoJS.algo.SHA512, secret);
        hmacHasher.update(path);
        hmacHasher.update(hash256.finalize());

        var hashInBase64 = this.CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hmacHasher.finalize());
        return hashInBase64;
    }
```

Comment: this does not create the same Signature as the function provided in the question